# Maximum likelihood as correspondence (or, How I hate the poor usage of Mathematics in Statistical textbooks)

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, random-variables, definition, parameter-estimation

Maybe the title was a bit much, but it describes both my question and my sentiment towards (what I perceive to be) the neglect, in statistical textbooks, of mathematics. The preamble to my question is this:

Consider a statistical experiment $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathscr{P})$ over the parameter space $\Theta = (0, \infty)$.

(By a statistical experiment I mean a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ together with a collection of probability measures indexed by $\Theta$, *i.e.*, $\mathscr{P} = \{ P_{\theta} \, | \, \theta \in \Theta \}$).

Assume that you have a collection of random variables $X_1, ..., X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} U(0, \theta)$, for every $\theta \in \Theta$.

With this information, a natural question one could ask is "what is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) of $\theta$?" To answer it, first we set up the likelihood function, which in this case will be $\mathcal{L} : \Theta \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0, \infty)$, defined as
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L}(\theta, x_1, ..., x_n) = \left[ \prod_{i = 1}^n \boldsymbol{1}_{[0, \, \theta]} (x_i) \right] \cdot \cfrac{1}{\theta^n}.
\end{equation*}

Here is where my troubles begin: Usually textbooks don't give you any of the specifics about the MLE function, in particular a common definition of the MLE estimator goes like this: "For a sample point $\boldsymbol{x}$, let $\hat{\theta}(\boldsymbol{x})$ be a parameter value at which $\mathcal{L}(\theta, \boldsymbol{x})$ attains its maximum as a function of $\theta$ with $\boldsymbol{x}$ held fixed." This is completely uninformative and a bad definition in my opinion, but it contains a hint of formality:
Notice that the MLE should be defined for every sample point (in our case, the sample space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ given the fact that we are operating on the space induced by the random vector $(X_1, ..., X_n)$, so the domain of the MLE should be $\mathbb{R}^n)$. Other times, authors are more explicit and they define the MLE as
\begin{equation*}
 \hat{\theta}_{MLE}(x) = \underset{\theta \, \in \, \Theta}{arg \, max} \; \mathcal{L}(\theta, x)
\end{equation*}
Notice that this cannot be just a standard function, that is, $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Theta$, simply because for some values $(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ either there are multiple $\theta \in \Theta$ that satisfy the maximization problem or it might not have any solution at all. In the problem I described above (finding the MLE of the uniform), both cases actually happen, which leads me to believe that the MLE is actually a correspondence, that is, $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\Theta)$ (where $\mathcal{P}(\Theta)$ is the set of parts of $\Theta$) and it would be

\begin{equation*}
         \hat{\theta}_{MLE}(x_1, ..., x_n) =
        \left\{
         \begin{array}{ll}
          \Theta, & \mbox{if } \exists \, i \in \{ 1, ..., n \} \; \text{such that} \;  x_i < 0 \\[3pt]
                \; \emptyset, & \mbox{if } \forall \, i \in \{ 1, ..., n \}, \; x_i = 0 \\[3pt] 
                 max \{ x_1, ..., x_n \}, & \mbox{if } (x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+} \; \text{and} \; \exists \, i \in \{ 1, ..., n \}, \;  \text{s.t.} \; x_i > 0.
         \end{array}
        \right. 
        \end{equation*}

My question amounts to asking if this interpretation is correct? If yes, how do we take the expectation of this statistic (or any moment)? Do we ignore the set aspect and stick to the function? If not, how is the MLE defined?

Comment: Why are you worried about cases where $x_i \le 0$? These cases happen with probability zero, so you are left with the well-defined $\max\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$.

Comment: The reason for this non-rigour is that the MLE is actually a very subtle estimator. But yes, in general, one needs to assume the MLE is a measurable function. (And your example as pointed out earlier, is not a good one).

Comment: @angryavian I'm mostly concerned with the definitional aspect of the theory (How is the MLE defined). Even though it is pretty clear that the set of nonpositive entries have probability zero, if the MLE is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ then these points matter for the function. Besides there are estimation problems in which the nonexistence or multiplicity of solutions spans sets which have positive probability. How should the MLE deal with those sets? Should we ignore them? As I said in the beginning, this post was made just so I could understand the foundational elements of the MLE.

Comment: @Andrew The example I brought forward may not be that good (however you want to judge that), but the problem still stands. As I said in my previous comment, there are cases in which either we have multiple solutions or no solutions at all for sets of points with positive probability. Then what should we do? With this consideration in mind, I reiterate the questions I made: is my interpretation correct? If yes, how do we take the expectation of this statistic (or any moment)? Do we ignore the set aspect and stick to the function? If not, how is the MLE defined?

Comment: Your example is not good because, as angryavian pointed out, the issues with MLE are not present in your example. The solution is to assume correspondence and measurability issues do not exist, or to restrict yourself to a regime where these issues do not exist. However, it is highly non-trivial to actually establish when these issues do not exist. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09753.pdf

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the article. I suppose now I understand your comment better. One potential solution is to restrict the codomain of the random variables $X_i$ to, for example, $(0, \infty)$ so we don't have to worry about any correspondence issues (in particular the likelihood function would be defined on $\Theta \times (0, \infty)^n$, which does not constitute a problem). Thanks for the insight.  Do you happen to know any good references to the existence, uniqueness and measurability concerns of the MLE? I would love to read more about it, but I feel I'm kinda stuck at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I am guessing that the books Asymptotic Statistics; Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes by Vaart would be a starting place. There is brief discussion here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406843/measurability-of-maximum-likelihood-estimator-under-conditions-from-lehmanns-t